# Не правильно работает Bootstrap меню на мобильных устройствах, как решить проблему?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Собственно уже перепробовал много вариантов: есть [проект](http://all2.devruso.ru/baikal/) на Bootstrap, возникла проблема с тем что меню не срабатывало на hover, но с помощью этого кода

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

эту ситуацию исправил, но возникла новая проблема, нельзя было при клике перейти на страницу, эту проблему решило убирание у ссылок атрибутта

```
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

все заработало, но нашлась третья проблема: на мобильных устройствах меню некорректно срабатывает: при клике на пункт открывается подменю (мы добавляем атрибут data-toggle="dropdown", но перейти по ссылке нельзя

```
function dropdownBack() {
    var Wsize = $(window).width();

    if (Wsize < 768) {
        $('.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav').find('.dropdown').find('a').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav').find('.dropdown').find('a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    }
}

dropdownBack();
$(window).resize(dropdownBack);
```

и также переход на страницу не работает по пункту родителю (Сохраним Байкал). Помогите исправить этот баг, чтобы на мобильных можно было и перейти по ссылке и открыть подменю.

Comment: Так у вас кроме 'baikal_save-baikal.html' больше и нет ни одной ссылки. Куда переходы-то из подменю должны осуществляться?

Comment: да хотя бы на эту ссылку, я проставлял ссылки, сейчас убрал, но если надо поставлю. Меня интересует работа самого меню на мобильных